# Connection logs from previous day

Tags: ip, logs

I have a problem. I have a vps running Ubuntu server that got ddossed yesterday and I would like to know what ip address it was coming from. We have an ip that we think might be the ddos, but we don’t know for sure.

Comment: What about `/var/log/auth.log`?

Comment: If you had a firewall like UFW on during that time, you may look at the UFW log entries.

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on the method of ddoss-ing that was used. You could ping your machine to death or use some DNS exploit, and unless you have some kind of ICMP-logging turned on (not default, not recommended either) it's very hard to find out on the OS level (say, on Ubuntu).

In some countries ddoss-ing is an offence and you could report it to the police also. Don't expect them to find out quickly though, or even pick up the report.

The recommended way of finding out is working together with your hosting provider where you rented the VPS and ask them to check on the router for logs where the ddoss was coming from.

Comment: I would also say router or firewall logs is the best bet.